# Is there anyway to delete rownames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I made a table like this table name a.

```
   variable relative_importance scaled_importance percentage
1      x005        68046.078125          1.000000   0.195396
2      x004        63890.796875          0.938934   0.183464
3      x007        48253.820312          0.709134   0.138562
4      x012        43492.117188          0.639157   0.124889
5      x008        43132.035156          0.633865   0.123855
6      x013        32495.070312          0.477545   0.093310
7      x009        18466.910156          0.271388   0.053028
8      x015        10625.453125          0.156151   0.030511
9      x010         8893.750977          0.130702   0.025539
10     x014         4904.361816          0.072074   0.014083
11     x002         1812.269531          0.026633   0.005204
12     x001         1704.574585          0.025050   0.004895
13     x006         1438.692139          0.021143   0.004131
14     x011         1080.584106          0.015880   0.003103
15     x003           10.152302          0.000149   0.000029
```

and use this code to order that table.

```
setorder(a,variable)
```

and want to get only second column.

```
a[2]

   relative_importance
12            380.4296
11            645.4594
15             10.1440
4            8599.7715
2           10749.5752
13            263.7065
5            8434.3760
6            7443.8530
7            3602.8850
10            935.6713
14            256.7183
3            9160.4062
1           12071.1826
9            1173.0701
8            1698.0955
```

I want to copy "relative_importance" and paste in Excel.
But, I couldn't delete the rownames. (12,11,15...,9,8)
Is there any way to print only "relative_importance"? (print without rownames or hide rownames)

Thank you :)

Comment: `print(a[2], row.names=FALSE)`, a probable duplicate.

Comment: thank you. i edited it :) and Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `writeClipboard( as.character(a$relative_importance) )` and paste it in Excel

Comment: I applied it, but i couldn't get any result. Could you let me know where can I get result of this? in Console? or another pane?

Comment: if a is a matrix then use a[,c("relative_importance")] instead of a$relative_importance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `csv` file, which you can open with Excel.

`write.csv(a[2], "myfile.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE`.

Note that the file will be created in your current working directory, which you can find by running the following code: `getwd()`.

On a different note, are you trying to get the column into Excel for further analysis? If you are, I encourage you to learn how to do that analysis in R.

Comment: I just wanted to organizing results in excel. But, I will learn how to do that in R. Thank you again!